# Prove / disprove: if $f(n)=O(g(n))$ then $2^{f(n)}=O (2^{g(n)})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

> Prove / disprove: if $f(n)=O(g(n))$ then $2^{f(n)}=O (2^{g(n)})$

This is related to: [Big-O: If $f(n)=O(g(n))$, prove $2^{f(n)}=O(2^{(g(n)})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482733/big-o-if-fn-ogn-prove-2fn-o2gn)

But I don't see how the answer there is right (I commented on that there) and I have a question about a different approach.

Can we use that since $2^x$ is a continuous positive function then it keeps signs of inequalities? i.e $a<b$ then $2^a<2^b$?

Comment: Note that $2^{ab}\neq 2^a 2^b$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yeah I see it now...

Comment: @Did From the duplicate auto-text: *If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question*.  That's exactly what this question did, and it shouldn't have been closed as a result.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes it ought to, since it was asking for an explanation about a posted answer and the right move was to first ask for it there, *then wait a little*, and then, if nothing came, to post a new question. Please see the delay between the comment asking for explanation there being posted and being answered.

Comment: I assumed David is from a different time zone, so the answer would probably come tomorrow for me and I had another question about this too so the answer didn't fully address my question. It doesn't matter now though. @Did