# Big-O: If $2^{f(n)}=O(2^{g(n)})$, prove $f(n)=O(g(n))$

Tags: asymptotics

It's similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482733/big-o-if-fn-ogn-prove-2fn-o2gn) question but upside down.

Suppose that both $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are nonnegative functions. If $2^{f(n)}=O(2^{(g(n)})$, is  $f(n)=O(g(n))$ true too? If not, give a counterexample.

Comment: Have you tried to find a counterexample? Which functions have you tested?

Comment: Thanks @AntonioVargas! I I thought about $f(n)=1$ and $g(n)=1/n$. This solve my real question as well. $2^{f(n)}=O(2^{g(n)log^k n})$ and $f(n)=O(g(n)log^k n)$ for $k>0$. Isn't it?

Comment: Can you prove it?

Comment: I'm not sure about it, from my understanding $g(n)$ should asymptote to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Bounded below by a positive constant is needed.  What if not?

Try $f(n) = 1+1/n$ and $g(n) = 1/n$.  Then
$$
2^{f(n)} = 2^{1+1/n} = 2 \cdot 2^{1/n} = 2\cdot 2^{g(n)} \quad\text{so}\quad
2^{f(n)} = O\big(2^{g(n)}\big).
$$
But
$$
f(n) = 1+\frac{1}{n}\quad\text{ is not } O\left(\frac1n\right)=O(g(n)) .
$$

Answer (score 0):

$2^{f(n)} =O(2^{g(n)})$ implies there exist M a real number and $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|2^{f(n)}| \leq M|2^{g(n)}|$ for all $n \geq n_0$.
Now take log both sides which becomes $|f(n)| \leq M^1+|g(n)|$ for all n greater than $n_0$. I think, if g(n) is bounded below by some positive number then certainly, what you are saying is true.

Comment: Taking $\log_2$ of both sides of $2^{f(n)} \leq M 2^{g(n)}$ yields $f(n) \leq \log_2 M + g(n)$. How do you find an $M'$ such that $\log_2 M + g(n) \leq M' g(n)$? It's impossible if $g(n) \to 0$ and $M > 1$.